# Ruby: what's the difference between initializing a string using quotes vs colon?

Tags: ruby

Whats' the difference between initializing a string using quotes vs preceding it with the  colon? I.e "bobo" vs :bobo. When you inspect them they appear the same but when you compare them the result evaluates to false.

```
irb(main):006:0> r = "bobo"
=> "bobo"
irb(main):007:0> puts r
bobo
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> t = :bobo
=> :bobo
irb(main):009:0> puts t
bobo
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> puts r == t
false
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> s = "bobo"
=> "bobo"
irb(main):012:0> puts r == s
true
=> nil
```

Comment: ONe is a string, one is a symbol.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBXGBbEbXZY

Comment: Your question is undefined because of presupposition failure. A string cannot be initialized with a colon.

Comment: What you are asking is very basic Ruby syntax, and is something covered at the start of Ruby tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Definitely, a presupposition failure :)

Comment: @Tin Man - do you have any specific tutorials in mind? I had been through a few and don't remember this being covered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"bobo"* is a string whereas *:bobo* is a symbol.

```
:bobo.class # => Symbol
"bobo".class # => String
```

[`String#==`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D)

> If obj is not a String, returns false. Otherwise, returns true if str <=> obj returns zero.

So according to the documentation `"bobo" == :bobo # => false` and `"bobo" == "bobo" # => true`. - This is expected.

```
puts :bobo 
# >> bobo
:bobo.to_s # => "bobo"
```

This is because `puts` applying `to_s` on the Symbol object `:bobo`. See [`Symbol#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_s)

Answer (score 5):

Notice the following:

```
"foo".object_id
 => 70353007334300
"foo".object_id
 => 70353007354360
:foo.object_id
 => 413928
:foo.object_id
 => 413928
```

Symbols are **cached** (same `object_id`) whereas strings are **instantiated every time**. Keep this in mind for performance knowledge but also keep in mind garbage collector ;)

Comment: interning for strings with `:`

Answer (score 4):

The [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)-like thing beginning with a colon is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html):

```
:bobo.class
# => Symbol
"bobo".class
# => String
```

When you `inspect` them, they look different:

```
:bobo.inspect
# => ":bobo"
"bobo".inspect
# => "\"bobo\""
```

When you print them with `puts` they look the same, because `puts` calls `to_s` on its arguments, and `:bobo.to_s` returns `"bobo"`:

```
:bobo.to_s
# => "bobo"
:bobo.to_s == "bobo"
# => true
```

If you'd like to understand better the differences and how Symbols are used, perusing the documentation linked to above is a good place to start, as is any Ruby tutorial.  This article is also worth reading: [The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

Answer (score 3):

The "string with a colon" as you say, is a symbol. While they are similar to strings, symbols are immutable. Mutable objects can be changed after assignment. Immutable objects(:symbols) can not be changed after assignment. They can only be overwritten. Ruby is unique and is such a dynamic language, things can and often do change at runtime. Symbols are more rigid and won't be unexpectedly changed at runtime.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory.

Comment: @sawa, not sure what you mean contradictory? can you elaborate?

Comment: A string is not a symbol. I guess you realized your mistake and edited it. To others: this answer originally said: "the string with a colon is a symbol".

Comment: It wasn't a mistake, just paraphrasing the way the question was asked. "...difference between initializing a string using quotes vs preceding it(string) with the colon?" I did add to make it clear I was paraphrasing the question. Not to be confusing. Thanks for pointing it out so I could make it clearer. Just making sure it wasn't something else.

Answer (score 2):

the main difference between symbol and string is memory allocation and mutability. strings can be altered anytime.

```
'prasad' << 'surase' => "prasadsurase" 
:prasad << 'surase'
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for :prasad:Symbol
```

also two strings with same value(eg 'prasad' and 'prasad') have two different memory locations and have different object ids.

```
'prasad'.object_id => 102809450 
'prasad'.object_id => 102894570 
'prasad'.object_id => 103057580
```

whereas two same symbols are the same and have the same memory location since there is only a single object.

```
:prasad.object_id => 2358408 
:prasad.object_id => 2358408 
:prasad.object_id => 2358408
```

also, when string is created, it needs to be allocated memory n when not referred, it needs to be garbage collected but symbols stay in memory throughout the programs operation and are not garbage collected when not referred. this affects the performance of the program. u can collect all the declared symbols as

```
Symbol.all_symbols.include?(:prasad) => true
```